# Delete method not deleting the employee of EmployeeStore

Tags: java, hashmap

My delete method doesn't seem to be functioning because the application fails to delete the employee when the user attempts to by entering the employees name.  What is supposed to happen is the following:

1. The user inputs the employee's name using a mnethod I have written called userInputByName.
2. The application searches the store for this employee.
3. The employee is removed.

Step 3 does not work when I then print out the store the employee is still there.

I will now show you my code.

```
MainApp()

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:        Case 3: Delete by Name.
//  Description: Choice 3 gives the user an option to delete an employee by name.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Delete by Name.");
                Employee employeeDelete = MenuMethods.userInputByName();
                Store.searchByName(employeeDelete.getEmployeeName());
                System.out.println("Your choice is: "+ employeeDelete);
                Store.remove(employeeDelete);
                break;
```

Employee

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Employee class.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class Employee
{
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Variables to be used in the employee store.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private String employeeName;
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeEmail;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:        Constructors.
//  Description:
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Employee(String employeeName, int employeeId, String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Overloading the constructor for the use with userInputByName method.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Employee(String employeeName) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:   Getters.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String getEmployeeEmail() 
    {
        return employeeEmail;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() 
    {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public int getEmployeeId() 
    {
        return employeeId;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:   Setters.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setEmployeeEmail(String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId)
    {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:   toString.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "\t\t\tEmployee\n" +
                "********************************************************************\n"+
                "Employee Name: "+ employeeName +"\n"+ 
                "Employee Id: " + employeeId +"\n"+  
                "Employee Email: " + employeeEmail;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Delete method

```
public Employee remove(Employee key) {
        // Remove the Employee by name.
        if (map.containsKey(key))
            return map.remove(key); // if it is there remove and return.
        else
            return null; // if its not there return nothing.
    }
```

Hashmap declaration

```
HashMap<String, Employee> map;
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public EmployeeStore() {
        map = new HashMap<String, Employee
```

SearchByName

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: Search by Name.
    // //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Employee searchByName(String employeeName) {
        Employee employee = map.get(employeeName);
        System.out.println(employee);
        return employee;
    }
```

UserInput

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:        userInputByName.
//  Description: This method is used in the MainApp to give the user capability to search by name.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static Employee userInputByName() 
    {
        // String temp is for some reason needed. If it is not included
        // The code will not execute properly.
        String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
        Employee e = null;
        System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
        String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();

        return e = new Employee(employeeName);

    }
```

Adding to the hashmap

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//   Create a Store named Store and add Employee's to the Store.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
        Store.add(new Employee("James O' Carroll", 18, "hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee("Andy Carroll", 1171, "yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee("Luis Suarez", 7, "gmail.com"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Hashmap` is declared as `HashMap<String, Employee> map`.

If you want to remove something from it then you need to pass in a `String`, not an `Employee`. Try something like:

```
public Employee remove(String key) 
{
    return map.remove(key);
}
```

There is no need to check if the `HashMap` contains the key before removing it.  The method will return `null` for you.

edit: I'm surprised that this didn't throw a compile-time error for you.

**edit2:** OK.  So you are creating your `Employee` object and then passing that into your `add()` method.  That's fine, but you need to have your `add()` method match the `remove()` method that you made.  So if you are doing `EmployeeStore.remove(<employee.getEmployeeName())` then you should make your `add()` method look like this:

```
public Employee add(Employee input)
{
    return map.put(input.getEmployeeName(), input);
}
```

This function does return an `Employee` object if there were previously one stored under that `Key`, but you can choose to ignore that value.  Having your `add()` method like this should make it match your `remove()` method.  Since you have an employee ID number you could even change your `Key` to that integer since it will probably be more unique than a name.

Comment: But then i will have a problem in my MainApp when im calling the other methods.

Comment: What problems would occur?  This is just standard implementation of the built in `remove()` function: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Comment: The function itself is perfect i understand where i went wrong but in my mainApp System.out.println("Delete by Name.");
    Employee employeeDelete = MenuMethods.userInputByName();
    Store.searchByName(employeeDelete.getEmployeeName());
    Store.remove(employeeDelete);
    break;    These methods are set to take an employee object.  Therefore changing the key to a string will hence have an error on the Store.remove()

Comment: sorry for the state of the code.  I do not know how to format it.

Comment: If you are putting the Employee into the HashMap based on the name, then just do `remove(<Employee>.getEmployeeName())`.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show how you add entries to the HashMap?  And could you also post the errors that you are getting?  I'll try to edit mine with a solution to fix the errors.

Comment: I get The method remove(String) in the type EmployeeStore is not applicable for the arguments (Employee).  Thats obviously because I made an object to equal the userInput method.  But i traced back and tried to make the UserInput method a string so that i could obviously get the methods working with a string object instead and it turns out the userInput method needs to take an Employee object.  BTW i edited the code.

Comment: I edited my post.  You should only have to change your add() method to get this to work.  Let me know if it works.